# Add quotes around alpha characters in alphanumeric strings using T-SQL which can begin end with alpha characters?

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, quotes, alphanumeric

I want to add quotes around alphabets in an alphanumeric string. For eg: If my string is 8AB8973, the output expected is 8'AB'8973. There is no specific pattern in which the numbers and characters will occur. I posted a similar question on StackOverFlow and someone provided me the following code which works for the above example. But it fails for the following strings. I have mentioned the example, expected output and what I receive using below code.
Eg 1 : First char of string is alpha = PAYGA0102. Expected : 'PAYGA'0102. Result received : PAYGA'0102
Eg 2 : Last char of string is alpha = 00086K. Expected : 00086'K'. Result received : 00086'K
Eg 3 : All are chars = ADEP Expected = 'ADEP'. Result received : ADEP.

I need to tweak the below code to include all the above conditions. I will loop the code later, but i need fix in the main patindex code to satisfy all conditions mentioned above. Code below is repetitive just to show the different results i am getting.

```
DECLARE @position INT;
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max);

SET @string = '9FX8173';

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
  SET @position = (SELECT Min(position)
                   FROM   (VALUES (Patindex('%[^''0-9][0-9]%', @string)),
                                  (Patindex('%[0-9][^''0-9]%', @string))) AS T(position)
                   WHERE  T.position > 0);

  IF @position IS NULL
    BREAK;

  SET @string = Stuff(@string, @position + 1, 0, '''');
END

PRINT @string;

SET @string = 'PAYGA0102'

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
  SET @position = (SELECT Min(position)
                   FROM   (VALUES (Patindex('%[^''0-9][0-9]%', @string)),
                                  (Patindex('%[0-9][^''0-9]%', @string))) AS T(position)
                   WHERE  T.position > 0);

  IF @position IS NULL
    BREAK;

  SET @string = Stuff(@string, @position + 1, 0, '''');
  END

  PRINT @string;

  SET @string = '00086K'

  WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
  SET @position = (SELECT Min(position)
                   FROM   (VALUES (Patindex('%[^''0-9][0-9]%', @string)),
                                  (Patindex('%[0-9][^''0-9]%', @string))) AS T(position)
                   WHERE  T.position > 0);

  IF @position IS NULL
    BREAK;

  SET @string = Stuff(@string, @position + 1, 0, '''');
  END

  PRINT @string;

  SET @string = 'ADEP'

  WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
  SET @position = (SELECT Min(position)
                   FROM   (VALUES (Patindex('%[^''0-9][0-9]%', @string)),
                                  (Patindex('%[0-9][^''0-9]%', @string))) AS T(position)
                   WHERE  T.position > 0);

  IF @position IS NULL
    BREAK;

  SET @string = Stuff(@string, @position + 1, 0, '''');
  END

  PRINT @string;
```

Comment: Just for completness is possible multiple character groups or only one. For example:  `AAA123BBB` --> `'AAA'123'BBB'` is a valid case?

Comment: Yes it totally is a valid case.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

With a copy of [patternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/) it's easy. And because the function is purely set-based you'll get much better performance than any RBAR based alternative.

**Solution against a variable**

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'ABC123ZZ888X';

select newstring = replace((
  select ''''+item+''''
  from dbo.patternSplitCM(@string, '[0-9]')
  order by ItemNumber
  for xml path('')),'''''','''');
```

**Against a table**

```
-- sample data
declare @yourtable table (someid int identity, string varchar(100));
insert @yourtable values ('ABC'),('123X'),('BBBCC44455555ZZ6P'),('CC923PP5522'),(NULL);

-- the only difference here is that I replaced @string with t.string
select someid, oldstring = string, newstring 
from @yourtable t
cross apply 
( select newstring = replace((
    select ''''+item+''''
    from dbo.patternSplitCM(t.string, '[0-9]')
    order by ItemNumber
    for xml path('')),'''''','''')) addquotes
```

**Results**

```
someid   oldstring           newstring
-------- ------------------- -----------------------
1        ABC                 'ABC'
2        123X                '123'X'
3        BBBCC44455555ZZ6P   'BBBCC'44455555'ZZ'6'P'
4        CC923PP5522         'CC'923'PP'5522'
5        NULL                NULL
```

Comment: But in this string 123X, the expected output gets me '123'X'. Whereas it needs to be 123'X'. I need to edit the first quote as its a number and not alphabet.